# Proper way to override values-night for different OS versions

Tags: android, android-styles

I want to implement night mode in my app. I referred to this site:
[DayNight Theme Android Tutorial with Example](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/daynight-theme-android-tutorial-example)

I see we need to make the `values-night` directory and override the `styles.xml` file inside it. I already have other different `values` directory like `values-v27` also overriding the `styles.xml` file. How do I implement the night theme for those specific directories? Like is it `values-v27-night` or is it `values-night-v27`? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can have specific values for the night and for any other resource qualifier. For your example, the resource directory name will be `values-night-v27`.
If you are unsure of the order, you can right click the `res` node in your project structure and go to New > Android Resources Directory, then fill you criteria and the name will be automatically generated.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

`values-night-v27` puts an **and** clause between two conditions `v27` and `night` , so it doesn't matter if you use `values-v27-night`.

Also if you put your values separately in `values-v27` and `values-night` an **or** clause will be applied